# What is the perfect way to avoid "beyond bounds" when using NSArray

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays

I knows some ways to avoid this, for example

```
if (index >= [_data count] || index < 0) return nil;
    return [_data objectAtIndex:index];
```

But should i aways do this? or are there any other solutions about this topic?

Comment: This question is a bit too open ended. Do you have a specific question about this?

Comment: I mean a solution which makes "beyond bounds" never ever happen again when using `[myarray objectAtIndex:index]`

Comment: There is no general solution. Every case is different. Sometimes you know the index is in range so you don't need to check. Sometimes it might be out of range so you need to check or simply let it crash indicating a bug in the app that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy, yet again, I'm getting suspicious... :) . In Objective-C, there are a few different ways to accomplish the same task. Similar to Perl vs Python, in Python there is only one way to accomplish something. In Perl, there are numerous ways. Think of Objective-C more in the Perl fashion, in terms of one-way implementation of a task.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd like to echo @rmaddy's comment, which is spot on:

> There is no general solution. Every case is different.

That said, there are other techniques you can use:

#### `firstObject` and `lastObject`

These methods will return the object, or `nil` if there is none.  These methods will never throw an exception.

#### Fast Enumeration

You can use fast enumeration and never need to check the indices:

```
NSArray *myStrings = @[@"one", @"two"];

for (NSString *thisString in myStrings) {
     NSLog(@"A string: %@", thisString);
}
```

#### Safe Category

You can add a category on `NSArray` if you find yourself doing this frequently:

```
- (id)safeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index >= [self count] || index < 0) return nil;
    return [self objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

See [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) if you aren't familiar with categories.

One downside of this is it may be harder to find errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In apple library NSArray objectAtIndex method:

```
objectAtIndex:
Returns the object located at the specified index.

- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
Parameters
index
An index within the bounds of the array.
Return Value
The object located at index.
```

You can use "NSUInteger index ;" so "if (index < 0)" could be omitted.

In my opinion, if you need to provide some interface to others, you may need to add these code to avoid "beyond bounds". 
But if your code just works for yourself, you need not to do the stuff because most of time what you needs is an object in the array but not the nil. If the index beyonds bound, there must be some logic error which you need to fix. Let exception goes and find your bug.

Comment: You should say that `index` should be an `NSUInteger`. But plenty of people use `int` instead.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, we can use `int` , but NSUInteger is recommended and need not to think about if it is negative.

Comment: I agree that people should use `NSUInteger`. But you don't have too so it is not "always" as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

U can swizzle the `objectAtIndex`method,before call `objectAtIndex`, invoke method like 'custom_objectAtIndex' to check if out of bounds .

```
+ (void)load{
    Method method1 = class_getInstanceMethod(objc_getClass("__NSArrayI"),@selector(objectAtIndex:));
    Method method2 = class_getInstanceMethod(objc_getClass("__NSArrayI"),@selector(custom_objectAtIndex:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(method1, method2); 
}


- (id)custom_objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    NSLog(@"~~~~~~~:%ld",count);
    if (index >= self.count) {
        return @"out of bounds";
    } else {
       return [self custom_objectAtIndex:index];
    }
}
```